# jquery sortable and serialize in database?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am close to finishing this but am stuck at how to get the values out of the database and display the `<li></li>` in the correct order with the correct link.

So far I have this:

**HTML**

```
    <ul id="navMenu">
    <li id="navMenu_1"><a href="http://www.example.com/home">Your Home</a></li>
    <li id="navMenu_2"><a href="#">Preferences</a></li>
    <li id="navMenu_3"><a href="#">Your Mailbox</a></li>
    <li id="navMenu_4"><a href="#">Game Updates</a></li>
    <li id="navMenu_5"><a href="#">Message Boards</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#navMenu').sortable({

opacity: '0.8',
containment: '#navMenu',
cursor: 'move',
revert: true,
tolerance: 'pointer',
align: 'y',
update: function() {
    $.ajax({data: {navMenuLayout: $('#navMenu').sortable('serialize')}});
}
});
```

**AJAX PHP**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['navMenuLayout'])) {

session_start();
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE layout SET navMenu = ? WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_REQUEST['navMenuLayout'], $_SESSION['id']));
}
```

Everything works and I get a string like this saved into my database, when a user changes the order of the list.

```
navMenu[]=3&navMenu[]=1&navMenu[]=5&navMenu[]=2&navMenu[]=4
```

From having this in the database how can I then get php to echo the html above in the correct order, with the correct text showing for each link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're storing the order of the navigation, you can put them in an array and then loop through the array to show the menu items in the correct order

See the example I've written below:

```
$nav_order = array("home" => '2',
                   "preferences" => '1',
                   "mailbox" => '4',
                   "game_updates" => '5',
                   "message_boards" => '3');

// Sort the menu items in to the right order
$sorted_order = sort($nav_order, SORT_NUMERIC);

// Start the list
echo '<ul id="navMenu">';

// Go through each item in the array, and show the menu item
foreach ($sorted_order AS $menu_key => $menu_order)
{
    switch($menu_key)
    {
        case "home":
              echo '<li id="navMenu_1"><a href="http://www.example.com/home">Your Home</a></li>';
              break;
        case "preferences":
              echo '<li id="navMenu_2"><a href="#">Preferences</a></li>';
              break;
        case "mailbox":
              echo '<li id="navMenu_3"><a href="#">Mailbox</a></li>';
              break;
        case "game_updates":
              echo '<li id="navMenu_4"><a href="#">Game updates</a></li>';
              break;
        case "message_boards":
              echo '<li id="navMenu_5"><a href="#">Message Boards</a></li>';
              break;
    }
}

// End the list
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try and implement this now, I got to where I was on my own but got stuck here, could you please explain why you have used switch and case instead of general if else? Will let you know how I get on!

Comment: No problem.  The reason for the switch case, is that it seems perfectly logical to use a switch case.  You could implement it with an if-else if you feel this will help you understand it better - although I've read that switch cases are faster.

Comment: Yes, I have never used switch statements before, but now I understand them it seems perfectly logical to use it, thanks Luke, this did the trick.